# Connect sqlplus in oracle

Tags: database, oracle

I want to connect user sys in sqlplus of Oracle. But after I connect, I type like this:

> SQL>sqlplus sys as sysdba password:123456
>
> Error: ORA-01030:insufficient
>   privilege warning:You are no longer to
>   connect oracle.

Does anyone help me to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to connect **as sysdba**, you must, in addition to be a member of privileged group and sqlnet.ora properly configured - use a **password file** and corresponding parameter configured in the parameter file.

Here are two useful links from the documentation:

- [Oracle Database Reference - REMOTE_LOGIN_PASSWORDFILE](http://download-east.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96536/ch1177.htm#1023215)
- [Oracle Database Administrator's Guide - Using Password File Authentication](http://download-east.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/dba.htm#1167)